# Error login facebook React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am having problems `logging` in to `react-native`, I followed all the corresponding steps, and at the time of logging it presents the following error

> cannot read property 'logInWithReadPermissions' of undefined

**AppDelegate.m**

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"Vesti"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];



  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
              openURL:(NSURL *)url
              options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                  openURL:url
                                                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                               annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                    ];
    // Add any custom logic here.
    return handled;
  }

@end
```

**Info.Plist**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb243123989464644</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>243123989464644</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>iORDER</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

**App.js**

```
import FBDSK, { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk'

_fbAuth() {

        LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
            function(result) {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                    alert('Login cancelled');
                } else {
                    alert('Login success with permissions: ' +
                        result.grantedPermissions.toString());
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
            }
        );

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it would be more easy if you  show  more of your code since i dont  get it from the above snippet and i would suggest you a library which i think more simple to use and [its here](https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login)